# creating external Panel files in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

So I'm currently working on a C# Windows Form App in Visual Studio 2017
What I'd like to do is create several different external Panel files, then switch them out on the main form as the user navigates around.
I used this same technique for a Java GUI before and it worked great. 
However I can't seem to figure out how to create the external Panel file, is it possible or am I just wasting my time and energy on the impossible?

(edit) So if anyone is interested I've found a work around for my problem.
By using a winforms user control class I was able to create a working substitute.

Comment: Post what you've got so far in your project, and that will help a person answer your question on where you are stuck. Otherwise, this question is too broad

Comment: Pray tell, what is an *external Panel file* ?

Comment: ok, maybe a poor choice of words

Comment: what I mean by 'external' is the panel is its own class outside of the form class. therefore an external panel file.
to use you simply create a new instance of that object and add it to the form

Comment: Maybe you can use MEF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/

Comment: look up the mdichildren property and how its used